# why Run-time for add-before for doubly-linked lists is O(1)?

Tags: list, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

In data structures, we say pushing an element before a node in singly-linked lists are O(n) operation! since there is no backward pointers, we have to walk all the way through the elements to get to the key we are going to add before the new element. Therefore, it has a linear run time.
Then, when we introduce doubly-linked lists, we say the problem is resolved and now since we have pointers in both directions pushing before becomes a constant time operation O(1).
I understand the logic but still, something is confusing to me! Since we DO NOT have constant time access to the elements of the list, for finding the element we want to add before, we have to walk through the previous element to get there! that is true that in the doubly-linked list it is now faster to implement the add-before command, but still, the action of finding the interested key is O(n)! then why we say with the doubly-linked list the operation of add before becomes O(1)?

Thanks,

Comment: The operation to find the element to add before is O(N) but once you have a item in the list it is an O(1) operation to add an item before it

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the std::list::insert() function takes an iterator to indicate where the insert should occur.  That means the caller already has this iterator, and the insert operation is **not** doing a search and therefore runs in constant time.

The find() algorithm, however, is linear, and is the normal way to search for a list element.  If you need to find+insert, the combination is O(n).

However, there is no requirement to do a search before an insert.  For example, if you have a cached (valid) iterator, you can insert in front of (or delete) the element it corresponds with in constant time.